# In a array of promises, how to access the ID used to fetch data

Tags: javascript

```
 Promise.all(arrayOfIds.map((id) => 
   axios.get(url);
   )).then((responses) => {
        /* here want to access the respective id used for fetching data, 
        so that I can add an extra property in to the corresponding response
        */
   });
```

Array of promises to concatenate input data with the response

Answer (score 2):

A simple loop should get you what you want:

```js
Promise.all(arrayOfIds.map((id) => 
   axios.get(url);
   )).then((responses) => {
        /* here want to access the respective id used for fetching data, 
        so that I can add an extra property in to the corresponding response
        */
        responses.forEach((response, index) => {
          response.id = arrayOfIds[index];
        });
        // do something with responses
   });
```

of if you prefer a manual loop instead of `forEach`:

```js
Promise.all(arrayOfIds.map((id) => 
   axios.get(url);
   )).then((responses) => {
        /* here want to access the respective id used for fetching data, 
        so that I can add an extra property in to the corresponding response
        */
        for (let i = 0; i < responses.length; i++) {
          responses[i].id = arrayOfIds[i];
        }
   });
```

The reason this works is that `Promise.all` guarantees that the resolved values will be in the same order as the array of promises passed to it, which in your case is the result of a `map()` call, which preserves the order.

So everything should line up in the end.

Answer (score 2):

You can also return a `Promise.all`, where one item in the passed array is the id, and the other is the `axios.get` Promise:

```
Promise.all(arrayOfIds.map((id) => Promise.all([
  id,
  axios.get(url)
]))).then((responses) => {
  for (const [id, response] of responses) {
    // ...
  }
});
```